# Does a period matter when specifying SQLite database name?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am a newbie in Android, Java, and SQLite. I am now reading two tutorials:

- One uses a period: [DATABASE_NAME = "MyAwesomeQuiz.db"](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/quiz-app-with-sqlite/part-3-sqliteopenhelper)
- And another one does not: [DATABASE_NAME = "BookDB"](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Could you tell me which one should I follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter. It's just a file name and both approaches result in valid file names. sqlite does not require any specific file naming convention. The files are placed under `databases` in your app's private directory so if you're browising the file system, it's easy to tell they are database files even if they do not have any extension.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of the extension `.db` on not is irrelevant as long as the name is valid for the OS's file system.  
I personally prefer **name + extension** because it's immediately indicative of the type of the file. 
Especially for databases that I have extracted from a device into my pc I need the extension.